# Accessing a OGC WMS server and publishing it to ArcGIS FlexViewer

Tags: wms, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am trying to publish an OGC WMS service to my Flex Viewer. Within the configuration files amongst a few other layers I have the following:

```
        <layer label="EARSS National Outage Map" type="wms" visible="false" visiblelayers="earss:national_outage_map" skipgetcapabilities="false" alpha="0.6"
                autorefresh="60" 
                url="https://earss.extranet.ornl.gov/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities/obs?srs=EPSG:4326">
```

The service does not appear within the TOC of the viewer. I tried the trick of creating "a service with a service" and that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

hi you are using wms as a service but you are using wfs methods in your url
so u have juste to change ur url and it will work

Ex:
url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspacename/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=entrepot:layername1"

Answer (score 1):

> url=https://earss.extranet.ornl.gov/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities/obs?srs=EPSG:4326

The WMS URL is incorrect, it should point to the service endpoint and not contain any parameters.

Take a look at the [ArcGIS Viewer for Flex](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#/WMS_WMTS_ArcIMS_WebTiled_and_Bing_Maps_layer_types/01m300000052000000/) documentation.  Your layer information should look like:

```
<layer 
  label="EARSS National Outage Map" 
  type="wms" 
  visible="false" 
  alpha="0.6"
  url="https://earss.extranet.ornl.gov/geoserver/ows"
  visiblelayers="earss:national_outage_map"
  imageFormat="png"
  skipgetcapabilities="false"
  version="1.1.1"/>
```